# Jquery Mobile adding content to ui-grid after document ready from jquery is fired off

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on some sort of small game, but i ran into a problem.

I am using Jquery Mobile.

The issue is simple, my dynamicly content will load visual wise,i do see a card backside, but the click event dosent fire off.  I suppect that my document ready from jquery has something todo with this.

I tried various different things eg refresh that usually do the trick with lists, but since this is a UI-Grid, this is different.

My exmaple code below is a short snippet of what and how the structure is.

I am searching for a way to refresh my content in the ui-grid-c, so that my click event can fire off.

In the bottom there is a  alert("I want to see this popup message");.  I want to see this pop up.

In my index.html file

```
<script src="js/events.js"></script>        
<script src="js/newgriditems.js"></script>
```

This is my static HTML JQM grid

```
<div class="ui-grid-c" id="cards">

</div>
```

I call this function from newgriditems.js

```
function newCards() {
    var new = '<div class="ui-block-a">
   <img src="img/backside.jpg" />
   </div>';

    $("#cards").html(new).trigger("create");
    $("#cards").page();
}
```

In events.js there is a

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".ui-grid-c div img").click(function() {
    alert("I want to see this popup message");
  });

}
```

It works, IF i add the content as static content.

Comment: remove `.ready()` never use it in jQM. change this `$(".ui-grid-c div img").click(function() {` to this `$(".ui-grid-c").on("click", "img", function() {`. you dont need `.page()` nor `.trigger('create')`

Comment: I tried what u suggested. I still dont get my wanted alert pop message.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UeRCZ/ check this

Comment: Yea hmm.. i guess the difference is that i have 2 files events.js and newgriditems.js.  Is this an issue?

Comment: ok yea i see.. $(document).on('pageshow', function () {  forgot this :9

Comment: for dynamically added items, you need to attach events as explain my demo and comment above. it doesn't matter if both are in separate files.

Comment: could you make an answer plse, so we can get this question sorted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, always avoid using `.ready()` in jQuery Mobile.

> **Important:** Use `$(document).bind('pageinit')`, not `$(document).ready()`
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event. This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.
>
> Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

When adding elements dynamically, you need to attach event this way

```
$('.static_parent').on('event', '.dynamic_element', function () {
 // code
});
```